# Can glassfishV3 host struts+spring+hibernate applications?

Tags: java, struts, glassfish-3

I have a webapp implemented using struts+spring+hibernate which needs to be hosted in  glassfishV3 along with a JavaEE6 application. Both applications will access the same database. Is it possible? What do I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your application is not using any EJB 2.0 stuff, its highly unlikely that you have any issue. I believe, you are good to go.

Comment: Does it mean that I could just deploy it in glassfish without any porting work to do? I don't have the webapp yet as it is developed by another team. Otherwise I could just try it out.

Comment: @sarah: Yes, that is what I mean. If you want to be sure, you can try to come up with a quick application, which does nothing, built on top of Spring+Hibernate+Struts and try to deploy it to the Glassfish server which is running that Java 6 application.